# Assume Sagemaker Notebook instance role from Docker container with default network mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker

I have an interesting use case and a problem.

We are leveraging **Sagemaker Notebooks** as a development environment for our data science teams. These notebooks are essentially EC2 instances with a (relatively) nice IDE (not as good as Cloud9, though).

In addition, we are running some docker containers on these instances. However, we are forced to use `--network=host` mode, otherwise, the role assigned to the Notebook Instance is not assumed inside the docker container.

On the host (here `1234567890` is our account number, and `DataScientist` is the role attached to the Sagemaker Notebook instance):

```
$ aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "AROAU2P5VGYMMVxxxxxJ:SageMaker",
    "Account": "1234567890",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::1234567890:assumed-role/DataScientist/SageMaker"
}
```

Running the same command inside a Docker container with `--network=host` produces the same result:

```
$ docker run --network host amazon/aws-cli sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "AROAU2P5VGYMMVxxxxxJ:SageMaker",
    "Account": "1234567890",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::1234567890:assumed-role/DataScientist/SageMaker"
}
```

However, it doesn't work with Docker `--network=bridge`:

```
$ docker run amazon/aws-cli sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "AROAIMGPPFPT5T6N7BYX6:i-0b2a9080d5ed1cb98",
    "Account": "366152344081",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::366152344081:assumed-role/BaseNotebookInstanceEc2InstanceRole/i-0b2a9080d5ed1cb98"
}
```

As you can see, it's a completely different role being assumed. Notice the account number 366152344081 and the role ARN - it's sth internal to AWS.

We would like to keep the default networking option for Docker (bridge) and at the same time be able to assume the correct role (the one attached to SageMaker Notebook instance e.g. `DataScientist` in our case) attached to the host system (Sagemaker Notebook). Are there any hacks (e.g. iptable rules, etc.) to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at the networks that were created on a clean Sagemaker Notebook instance, we can notice a user-defined bridge network named `sagemaker-local`:

```bash
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
f1d5a59a8c9e        bridge              bridge              local
6142e6764495        host                host                local
194adfb00f0a        none                null                local
99de6c086aa8        sagemaker-local     bridge              local
```

If we then attach to this custom bridge, we will be able to assume the correct role (the one attached to the Sagemaker Notebook instance itself):

```bash
$ docker run --network sagemaker-local amazon/aws-cli sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "AROAU2P5VGYMMVxxxxxJ:SageMaker",
    "Account": "1234567890",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::1234567890:assumed-role/DataScientist/SageMaker"
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

As of this writing (10 Dec 2021) you don't need to attach to `sagemaker-local` bridge network anymore, the default `bridge` will work as well (note `--network bridge` is implicit in this call):

```bash
$ docker run amazon/aws-cli sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "AROAU2P5VGYMMVxxxxxJ:SageMaker",
    "Account": "1234567890",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::1234567890:assumed-role/DataScientist/SageMaker"
}
```

Make sure you restart your SageMaker Notebook instance.

Also, [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/mxnet_gluon_mnist/setup.sh) I found some manual patching (iptables etc.), but with the update it's already patched.

Thanks to AWS who fixed this :)

---

**UPDATE (October 2022)**
It looks this had been fixed only in `notebook-al2-v1` and `notebook-al2-v2`. The problem with the `notebook-al1-v1` is that the network patch for the `sagemaker-local` user-defined bridge network is applied only once the instance is started, which means that after a Notebook restart one would need to apply the [network patch](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker-python-sdk/mxnet_gluon_mnist/setup.sh#L80) manually.